# Default template class lambda

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

Lets say you have a template function that takes a "collection" and possibly a "transform" lambda:

```
template<typename Collection, typename Transform>
void DoIt(const Collection &c, Transform transform)
{
    for(auto &item: c)
    {
        std::cout << transform(item);
    }
}
```

But I want a default Transform of a lambda that simply returns a reference to it's argument. This way if Collection::value_type supports << into streams, you can just call

```
DoIt(collection);
```

but if it doen't, you can call:

```
DoIt(collection, [](const collection::value_type &item) { item.ToString();});
```

Comment: Did you have a problem with this particular default argument case, or default arguments in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the simplest answer is to overload the function, and have one call the other:

```
template<typename Collection, typename Transform>
void DoIt(const Collection &c, Transform transform)
{
    for(auto &item: c)
    {
        std::cout << transform(item);
    }
}

template<typename Collection>
void DoIt(const Collection &c)
{
    DoIt(c, [](auto &item) -> decltype(item) { return item; });
}
```

Or if you really want just one template for some reason, you'll need a function-like class that just passes through its argument.

```
namespace std_compat {
    struct identity
    {
        template<typename T>
        constexpr T&& operator()(T&& obj) const noexcept
        { return std::forward<T>(obj); }

        using is_transparent = void;
    };
}

template<typename Collection, typename Transform = std_compat::identity>
void DoIt(const Collection &c, Transform transform = {})
{
    for(auto &item: c)
    {
        std::cout << transform(item);
    }
}
```

This does also allow users to do something like `DoIt<decltype(c), std::negate<>>(c);`. That doesn't seem particularly good or bad.

Note [`std::identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/identity) is coming in C++20.

Comment: Very nice. I like both solutions. Probably the second one better, as it's more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Function object that returns a reference to x
struct SelfReference
{
    template<class T>
    auto operator()(T& x) const -> T&
    {
        return x;
    }
};

// default template argument selects SelfReference    
// also note default argument
template<typename Collection, typename Transform = SelfReference>
void DoIt(const Collection &c, Transform transform = Transform())
{
    for(auto &item: c)
    {
        std::cout << transform(item);
    }
}
```